# Paperclip aws-sdk error: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip, aws-sdk

I'm currently running into the `uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS` error when I attempt to upload files to my server.  I understand this to be typically caused by running an older version of paperclip, before they added support for aws-sdk-v2.  The strange thing is that I'm running the latest paperclip version (4.3.1) which, [according to its github page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1764#issuecomment-137194127), includes aws-sdk-v2 support.

Honestly, I'm not sure what more I can say about this.  I checked the error log and the above is the only complaint it has.  Do I need to do anything special to run v2 with paperclip?  Thanks to anyone who can shine any light onto this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of some folks over at github.  [(See the thread here.)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2021)

Basically it seems that paperclip 4.3.1 doesn't entirely support v2 yet.  A week after it was released or so, a commit was pushed to the master that gets past this error.  It appears not to be perfect but here's how I made it work.

You can specify this particular revision of paperclip to bundler with the following line:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git=> 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip', :ref => '523bd46c768226893f23889079a7aa9c73b57d68'
```

More information on this sort of thing can be found [here.](http://bundler.io/git.html)

You will need to specify the REGION of your in your paperclip defaults.  This can be done by dropping a `:s3_region=> 'us-west-2'` (or whatever your region is) into your `paperclip_defaults`.  Simply specifying the endpoint or host will not be enough.  You can look yours up [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

Also slightly confusing is the error message if the above isn't done properly:

> missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']

1. I couldn't get the recommended environment variable to work.
2. The `:region` option is somewhat misleading as it needs to be written `:s3_region`

Answer (score 7):

the issue is written here:

http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/TxFKSK2QJE6RPZ/Upcoming-Stable-Release-of-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby-Version-2

try to change your Gemfile to:

```
  gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However the point is that I want to use v2 and (according to paperclip's github page) this should have been resolved in version 4.3.1, released about a month ago.

Comment: I think support for aws-sdk v2 wasn't released until Paperclip v5